# Does Maven support properties inheritance?

Tags: maven-2, inheritance, properties, module

Let's say  I have a property foo defined in my parent POM. Is it possible to access the "foo" propery in any of the children?

To give you a bit of context, I am working on a multi-module maven project with inheritance.

I did search the web and some forums for a while and could not find the answer.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, they are inherited by children poms. Did it not work when you tried it out?

Comment: I've discovered that I had a small typo in the child pom. The version number of the parent POM was incorrect which caused the child not to be able to fetch its parent's properties. It is working now.

Comment: @Guillaume glad to hear you got it working. I hope I at least pointed you in the right direction then. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, properties are inherited from parent pom. You can access them via `${property.name}`

Here is an example where we inherit the property `jackson.version` from the parent pom.

**PARENT POM**

```
<!-- We define the property here -->
<properties>
    <jackson.version>2.9.0</jackson.version>
</properties>
```

**CHILD POM**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-json-org</artifactId>
    <!-- We reference the property in the child pom -->
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</plugin>
```